# Font face (Wisdom Script) rendering issue

Tags: css, font-face

Project link:

```
http://50.87.144.37/~projtest/team/design/AHG/brochure/1/demo.html
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Conv_Wisdom Script AJ';
    src: url('fonts/Wisdom Script AJ.eot');
    src: local('☺'), 
         url('fonts/Wisdom Script AJ.svg') format('svg'), 
         url('fonts/Wisdom Script AJ.ttf') format('truetype'), 
         url('fonts/Wisdom Script AJ.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Font name is "Wisdom Script". The descenders are getting cut. I have tried all the solutions, I can't seem to figure out the issue here.

Following is how the font is being displayed:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
font-family: 'LatoRegular';
    src: url('../fonts/Lato-Reg-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/Lato-Reg-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/Lato-Reg-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/Lato-Reg-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/Lato-Reg-webfont.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
```

Comment: No effect. There literally is no solution for this issue, as far as I can see.

Comment: Google font sheet? I am hosting the fonts on the server.

Comment: does your html's head part contains something like this <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>